# Redis Not Loading In Codeship

Tags: redis, codeship

Our jobs service test suite expects a Redis database to connect to in order to run its test cases. We're running into an issue where sometimes this jobs service fails to load in Redis and sometimes it doesn't.

We've followed the Codeship guide to the dot, and are finding that sometimes, our service is unable to connect to Redis while sometimes it is. I've tried switching Redis versions and this does not seem to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it would be appropriate to [implement a Docker healthcheck on your service](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/services/#sts=HEALTHCHECK).